# PHP array search within array

Tags: php, arrays, string-matching

```
$keywords = array('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'white');

$strings = array(
'She had a pink dress',
'I have a white chocolate',
'I have a green balloon',
'I have a chocolate shirt',
'He had a new yellow book',
'We have many blue boxes',
'I have a magenta tie');
```

In reality the `strings` array is really huge (50k+ entries).

What is the best way of running search and extracting the matching strings **only**?

Comment: If the data comes from a database, you should filter there already. Otherwise you can use `array_filter()`

Comment: @Shafizadeh it's the other way round, need to check if any of the keywords exist in every string.

Comment: In each string, you mean? Otherwise your small example already gives no results.

Comment: @GolezTrol if a string contains any of the words from the **keywords** array then the condition is true.

Comment: @jeroen I am working on array_filter right now. :)

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($strings,'filter');

function filter($a)
{
    $keywords = array('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'white');

    foreach ($keywords as $k)
    {
        if (stripos($a,$k) !== FALSE)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Didn't know you could actually pass an array to `stripos`

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: And you can't, it throws `stripos(): needle is not a string or an integer`

Comment: @adeneo Avoided this problem with a loop. Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: @Bengali You're probably not using >PHP5.5. Easily fixed, move the function out to be defined elsewhere, and reference it in `array_filter()`.

Comment: For performance reasons I would define `$keywords` outside of your filter function and include it with the use statement.

Answer (score 4):

Use `array_filter` to filter the `$strings` array.
Split the strings into an array, then trim each word, and use `array_intersect` to check if the array of words contains any of the `$keywords`.

```
$result = array_filter($strings, function($val) use ($keywords) {
    return array_intersect( array_map('trim', explode(' ', $val)) , $keywords);
});
```

Comment: I would rather use the use statement in you lambda function instead of the global keyword.

Comment: @flec - I really don't like `use`, but as the keywords probably doesn't change, there shouldn't be any issues here, so I agree, and edited.